# match with group in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to use match function with group in nodeJS. I have following string and code

```
const text = "asda asd asd notmatch-1234 asd asdf [stackoverflow-1234] 123 ad asd"
const matches = text.match(/\[\s*(\w+-\d+)\s*\]/g)
```

after printing out, matches I get matches: `[ '[stackoverflow-1234]' ]`
but I would like to use matches as `[ 'stackoverflow-1234' ]` not inlcude notmatch-12345 how can I do it?

Comment: can't you just access that with `matches[0]`

Comment: no, with matches[0] i have `[stackoverflow-1234]` but i only want `stackoverflow-1234`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `exec`

```js
const text = "asda asd asd notmatch-1234 asd asdf [stackoverflow-1234] 123 ad asd"
const matches = /\[\s*(\w+-\d+)\s*\]/g.exec(text)

console.log(matches[1])
```

Comment: If you talking about square brackets `[ ]` around `stackoverflow-1234`, then when you do `match` it capture whole regex condition, not only part in brackets `( ... )`. Exec capture both, first element in array same as `match`, second - remember part from `( ... )`

Answer (score 0):

This code will extract the result you need:

```
const text = "asda asd asd asd asdf [stackoverflow-1234] 123 ad asd"
const matches = text.match(/\s*(\w+-\d+)\s*/g)
```

Comment: i do not want to have notmatch-1234

Comment: i have `notmacth-1234` or `[xxxx-123]` in my text, I want to get `xxxx-123` for return

Comment: Technically inaccurate answers should not be flagged as low-quality answers.